# сохранение данных пользователя после нажатия на кнопку aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram, бот, aiogram-3.x

Мне нужно сохранить логин и пароль пользователя, пытаюсь реализовать это через состояния. Проблема в том, что после нажатия на кнопку "Решить тест" мне нужно, чтобы вывелось ботом сообщение "Введи свой логин", и сохранить ответ пользователя в переменную, потом так же сделать с паролем, но вместо этого сообщение "Введи свой логин" появляется вверху диалога, где обычно висит "Загрузка".

```
class Form(StatesGroup):
    login = State()
    password = State()

@router.callback_query(F.data == 'test') # то есть после нажатия на кнопку "Решить тест" (callback_data = 'test')
async def test(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer(text="Введи свой логин:")
    await state.set_state(Form.login)

@router.message(Form.login)
async def login(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(login=message.text)
    await message.answer(text="Введи свой пароль:")
    await state.set_state(Form.password)

@router.message(Form.password)
async def password(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(password=message.text)
    await message.answer(
        text='Отлично!'
    )
    await state.clear()
```

[image: скрин работы бота после нажатия на кнопку "Решить тест"]

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял, вам нужно отправить сообщение в чат, а не уведомление.
Для этого нужно обратиться к `CallbackQuery`

Хэндлер будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
@router.callback_query(F.data == 'test') # то есть после нажатия на кнопку "Решить тест" (callback_data = 'test')
async def test(message: types.Message, callback: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await callback.message.answer(text="Введи свой логин:")
    await state.set_state(Form.login)
```

Не забудьте импортировать `CallbackQuery`, если это не сделано